# AngularJS bind data to a compiled element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating elements inside a for loop using `$compile` and I need to bind data to them.

```
for (var item in data) {
    var elem = $compile('<panel ng-model="item"></panel>')($scope)[0];
    container.append(elem);
}
```

How can I get the panel directive to access the item data? I have to append the elements manually, so I can't use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `$scope.item = { someObject };` ?

Comment: @OmriAharon Could be, but my case is a bit different. I changed the question so you can see why I can't to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem like this:

```
for (var index in data) {
    var elem = $compile('<panel data="data[' + index + ']"></panel>')($scope)[0];
    container.append(elem); // pseudocode line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do a loop and compile for each item. That would be bad performance for your app. Do:

```
$scope.data = data;
var elem = $compile('<div ng-repeat="item in data"><panel ng-model="item"></panel></div>')($scope)[0];
container.append(elem);
```

You place `data` on the `$scope`, because that's how the binding occurs. Note that the HTML you write is compiled against a specific $scope.

I think you can do without the `[0]` as well, but not sure.